# MongoDB Atlas interaction with PowerShell

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I need help with the connection MongoDB atlas API with PowerShell. With bash, it works perfectly

```
    curl --include --user "{PUBLIC-KEY}:{PRIVATE-KEY}" --digest \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/orgs/{ORG-ID}?pretty=true"
```

but I'd like to do the same thing Powershell, Can someone help with that? (

Comment: Does this help - https://powershell.org/forums/topic/invoke-rest-method-in-powershell/

Comment: Hey @RamanSailopal Thank you so much, yes it works like hell :D

Answer (score 1):

@RamanSilopal Thank you so much for the link :)
I've converted it to PowerShell like that:

```
$ApiPrivateKey 
$ApiPublicKey
$Uri = 'https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/{ORG-ID}/accessList?pretty=true'
[securestring]$secStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $ApiPrivateKey -AsPlainText -Force
[pscredential]$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($ApiPublicKey, $secStringPassword)
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -ContentType Application/Json -Headers @{Authorization = “Basic $base64AuthInfo”} -Credential $credential -Method Get
```